# Reducing multiple sets of <div><br></div> to one set of <div><br></div> with preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I can't seem to figure this one out. I figured out how to reduce multiple `<br>` to one doing this:

`$text = preg_replace("/(<br\s*?>\s*)+/", "<br>", $text);`

But how would I reduce multiple sets of `<div><br></div>`to just one set of `<div><br></div>`

Will it be like this?

`$text = preg_replace("/(<br\s*?><div\s*?><\/div\s*?>\s*)+/", "<div><br></div>", $text);`

It doesn't do anything for some reason.

Comment: Looks like that should work. It doesn't?

Comment: The great question is why you need to do that? In other words, if you want a "well formatted" html document without useless spaces, tags... why you don't extract the data you need and then produces a new html document that fits your requirements?

Comment: Actually I just find out what was placing that gap in the rich text editor. So I removed it. But this still doesn't work: `$text = preg_replace("/(<br\s*?<div\s*?><\/div\s*?>\s*)+/", "<div><br></div>", $text);`

Answer (score 0):

There was just a simple typo there. I accidentally reversed the order.

It should be:

`$text = preg_replace("/(<div\s*?><br\s*?><\/div\s*?>\s*)+/", "<div><br></div>", $text);`

I switched div and br around. It works now.